# Android Pie: Enable "Record all calls automatically" programmatically

Tags: android, call-recording

**Call recording APIs doesn't work on Android 9 anymore**

Inbound & Outbound call recording on Android 9 doesn't work anymore using MediaPlayer. Only one sided voice is recorded (ignoring incoming voice).

With new Android 9 OS, it comes with in-built feature of turning on automatic call recordings. A solution to this could be to use the default phone system app, by enabling record all calls automatically.

So far only manual steps have been documented as mentioned below:

**Vivo**
Go to Settings > System app settings > Phone > Call recording to enable Record all calls automatically

**Xiaomi**
Steps may differ

**Samsung**
Steps may differ

**Need to achieve this programmatically**

1. I am **looking for a solution to do this step programmatically keeping all mobile proprieties under consideration.**
2. Also **need to fetch the default recording path programmatically (from settings on android phone) where the recording is auto-saved after call ending.** For Vivo phones, this recording path is **Internal_Memory/Recorder/Call/.** It varies depending on mobile manufacturer.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where you able to find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem of finding the default path of the recorder. I got all the media files from storage with extension .mp3,.aac etc., and sorted it based on last modified name. The last file name and path gives the path of the default recorder.

`TreeMap<Date, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>(all .mp3,.aac etc., files);`

` File[] listRecFiles = song.listFiles();

```
            for (File filesName : listRecFiles) {

                if (filesName.getName().endsWith(extension)) {

                    modifdate = modifiedDate(filesName.getPath().toString());
                    songMap.put(modifdate, filesName.getPath());
                }
            }`
```